# ASP.NET Core 3.1/5.0 Core Consume SOAP - Basic Authentication problem

Tags: asp.net-core, wcf, asp.net-web-api, web-applications

I need help configuring an SOAP request with basic authentication (http) in ASP.NET 5.0 Core/ ASP.NET 3.1 Core (VS2019).

I have built an ASP.NET Core Web API (.NET 3.1/5.0) project in order to consume a SOAP service that have basic authentication. But my code fails to send the basic authentication data to the service, when I run the project in VS2019 I get this exception:

**Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="test"'**

The SOAP service is configured by .NET Core "Connected Services" (Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider) with the WSDL.

I'm trying to create the http binding with the following code:

```
MyService.UpdateReq invoiceInfo = new MyService.UpdateReq();
MyService.JRPClient updateREQ = new MyService.JRPClient();

((BasicHttpBinding)updateREQ.Endpoint.Binding).Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;

((BasicHttpBinding)updateREQ.Endpoint.Binding).Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Basic;


updateREQ.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
updateREQ.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pwd";

MyService.ResponseType response = new MyService.ResponseType();

response = updateREQ.UpdateReq(invoiceInfo);
```

Also I have changed the %PortTypeChannel file with:

```
private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
        {
            
        
            System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
            result.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport; 
            result.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
            result.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Basic;

return result;
```

But now it fails with other message:

**Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Private.ServiceModel.dll
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Private.ServiceModel.dll but was not handled in user code
The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'**

I tryed the soap service with soapUI, added the basic authentication to it and it worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to code to Base64 the user and password:

```cs
MyService.JRPClient updateREQ = new MyService.JRPClient(); // SOAP Client 

updateREQ.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
updateREQ.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pwd";

MyService.ResponseType response = new MyService.ResponseType();

using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(updateREQ.InnerChannel)) 
{
    var httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    httpRequestProperty.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(updateREQ.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName + ":" + updateREQ.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password));

    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;

    response = updateREQ.UpdateReq(invoiceInfo); // Consume SOAP service
}
```